# Code saves my file lots of times instead of one

Tags: excel, vba

I got a few codes from the internet to automatically save my file on specific time, creating a new file with a date and time.

Instead of one, random files are created every second. Yesterday I had 200 files created. I have a few codes for saving, one after every action taken in the workbook, one to prevent closing the file and one to do the copy with the date and time name.

I know I have plenty of saving codes but do not know which one to remove to stop saving the file n-times every day.

The code in my workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    'If Weekday(Date) = 5 Then
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("23:30:00"), "copySheets"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    'Step 1: Check to see if cell C7 is blank
    If sheets("Trailers").Range("Z1").Value = "" Then
    'Step 2: If cell is blank, cancel the close and tell user
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "NOPE !!!"
    'Step 3: If cell is not blank, save and close
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_WindowResize(ByVal Wn As Window)
    Wn.WindowState = xlMaximized
    ActiveWindow.EnableResize = False
End Sub
```

The code in my Module for creating a new file with date and time.

```
Sub copySheets() 

    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim newWkb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim newWks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim sheets As Variant
    Dim varName As Variant
    '------------------------------------------------------------
     'Clearing all the values every Saturday
     'If Weekday(Date) = 7 Then
     'Worksheets("Trailers").Range("A3:D307").ClearContents
     'Worksheets("Trailers").Range("G3:G307").ClearContents
     ' Worksheets("Trailers").Range("J3:J307").ClearContents
      ' Worksheets("Trailers").Range("M3:M307").ClearContents
       ' Worksheets("Trailers").Range("P3:P307").ClearContents
       ' End If
       ' Application.OnTime TimeValue("23:30:00"), "copySheets"
    'Define the names of worksheets to be copied.
    sheets = VBA.Array("Trailers")

    'Create reference to the current Excel workbook and to the destination workbook.
    Set wkb = Excel.ThisWorkbook
    Set newWkb = Excel.Workbooks.Add

    For Each varName In sheets

        'Clear reference to the [wks] variable.
        Set wks = Nothing

        'Check if there is a worksheet with such name.
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wks = wkb.Worksheets(VBA.CStr(varName))
        On Error GoTo 0

        'If worksheet with such name is not found, those instructions are skipped.
        If Not wks Is Nothing Then
            'Copy this worksheet to a new workbook.
            Call wks.Copy(newWkb.Worksheets(1))

            'Get the reference to the copy of this worksheet and paste
            'all its content as values.
            Set newWks = newWkb.Worksheets(wks.Name)

        End If

    Next
    'ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & " Forecasting" & ".xlsm"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "report"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "report " & Format(CStr(Now()), "dd-mmm (hh.mm.ss AM/PM)") & ".xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: You have some strange issues in your code... Firstly, your `copySheets() ` sub creates as many workbooks as sheets exist in `sheets` array variable. What does `Array("Trailers")` refers? Then you are saving the workbook unjustified often.  Once after it has already SavedAs, then in `Workbook_SheetChange` event (each time you change the active sheet...

Comment: "Trailers" is my Sheet and it is only one in my file. I think the `Array("Trailers")` refers the code to copy only this sheet from my file if I have more than one. The `Workbook_SheetChange` is for to be saved after every entry from the employees, also I think I added it because if it's not saved when the Sub "Copy sheets" activate it won't save the new data.

Comment: In such a case, why not you simply set it like `set varName = wkb.Worksheets("Trailers")` and no need of any iteration between one array element?

Comment: And `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True` in the `BeforeClose` event is completely useless, unless you do not want to stay in an infinite loop. In order to avoid the loop you can use `Application.EnableEvents = False` before the line in discussion and `Application.EnableEvents = True` after... Anyhow, your workbook was saved in the sub, why again `SaveChanges:=True`? Only to loose some time?

Comment: Thank you! Good point. I will remove the whole ` Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True` in my `BeforeClose`. No one actually using the close button, it is just in accidental closure and this code was first, before the other save codes :) That is why it is still there.

Comment: Ok, I removed `Else ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True` from  `BeforeClose` but again it saved my file 15 times (well not 200 but it is random, some days is 10 some days 40 times). So the problem is not from this part of the code. Any idea?

Comment: What i said was connected to the fact that your code looses time and resources saving to workbook so many times... With **what name** are the workbook in discussion saved again and again? You have to put a Break point on your first code line, and then press F8 to run line by line and see where it saves the workbook again... Can you update your post with your last modifications?

Comment: It is saving with this name : "report 06-Feb (11.30.00 PM).xlsx" and then every second "report 06-Feb (11.30.01 PM).xlsx"... and so on.

Comment: Ok..I found finally what is causing the problem but don't know how to fix it. If a user fill a cell the file save itself automatically, so if they fill up 100 cells it will save 100 times but on the same file (not save as). Then when the code start for the Save as with different name and date it will saves the file 100 times! Or the N times of the filled cells. :O Why?

Comment: But you have been prevented about that by @user12851479. I thought you eliminate that line from the specific event... You simple delete all `Workbook_SheetChange` event. Nothing wrong will happen.

Comment: I eliminated `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    'Step 1: Check to see if cell C7 is blank
    If sheets("Trailers").Range("Z1").Value = "" Then
    'Step 2: If cell is blank, cancel the close and tell user
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "NOPE !!!"
    'Step 3: If cell is not blank, save and close
   THIS PART **** Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True*****
    End If
    End Sub` 

but I left `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save .......

Comment: I didn't evaluate the use of the other events... Why didn't you eliminate only the problematic event and try to understand what the others do. Only after that you could eliminate them, but is mor wise to do that step by step...

Comment: I removed the code `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub` 
but now it doesn't want to save the file. That is why I put this code so to be saved after every entry and to be saved on the specific time. But apparently is messing around with the whole code.

Comment: I would suggest you posting the code which remained after your modifications. Theoretically, removing those events, it should be saved by the main `copySheets` sub. Post, at least, this sub...

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most likely this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

within your `Workbook_BeforeClose` sub.

The way the before close sub works, is that it runs the code in the sub, and then closes automatically.

The issue is that within the sub, you also specify to close it *again*. Meaning it will re-initiate another closing sequence, run the sub again, encounter the close line again and... You have yourself a recurring loop. If you replace `Activeworkbook.Close` by `Activeworkbook.Save` it will make sure your changes are saved, and the workbook will be closed automatically at the end of the sub.

[Relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59455443/11936678)

Comment: Thank you both, I will edit my code and I hope everything will be fine :)
 Like I said I am still new and trying to learn as much as possible VBA and not only to edit codes from the web.

Answer (score 0):

For now my Workbook code looks like this :

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
 'If Weekday(Date) = 5 Then
 Application.OnTime TimeValue("23:30:00"), "copySheets"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
'Step 1: Check to see if cell C7 is blank
If sheets("Trailers").Range("Z1").Value = "" Then
'Step 2: If cell is blank, cancel the close and tell user
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "NOPE !!!"
'Step 3: If cell is not blank, save and close
End If
End Sub




Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

And my Module code  Sub copySheets() is still the same.

Comment: I found the solution. The whole code "Copy_Sheets" was the problem, so I just found a better one, smaller and effective.
`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wbPath As String
ThisWorkbook.Save
wbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs wbPath & "\Plan_" & Format(Now, "yyyy_mm_dd  hmmAM/PM") & ".xlsm"
End Sub`